# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected '"](?P<src>.+?)['"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with my WP site, I've added "comments" in supports array of Functions.php file in order to enable comments for custom post types. and then got the error, I'm not sure who it's related to these changes.

Could you please tell me what's the issue is? I'm noob in php unfortunately.
The error is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected '"](?P<src>.+?)['"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'
in /var/www/vhosts/kudatoday.kz/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/functions.php on line 1575
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QOI5.png)

Line 1575 bellow:

```
if ( preg_match( '/^<img.+src=['"](?P<src>.+?)['"].*>/', $image, $match ) ) {
        if ( isset( $match['src'] ) ) {
            return $match['src'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have an unescaped single quote in your regex.

Comment: if ( preg_match( '/^<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/', $image, $match ) ) {
        if ( isset( $match['src'] ) ) {
            return $match['src'];
        }
    }